# Searching value range rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add another search value in the scope and add it into the `terms.map`
and pass it on to the where query, I want to have min and a max value?

```
  scope :search_query, lambda { |query|
  return nil  if query.blank?

  # condition query, parse into individual keywords
  terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)

  # replace "*" with "%" for wildcard searches,
  # append '%', remove duplicate '%'s
  terms = terms.map { |e|
    (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
  }
  num_or_conds = 2
  where(
    terms.map { |term|
      "(LOWER(students.first_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(students.last_name) LIKE ?)"
    }.join(' AND '),
    *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conds }.flatten
  )
}
```

What i would like to do

```
.where(column_name BETWEEN #{value1} AND #{value2})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain scopes in rails by just calling where repeatedly:

```
Thing.where(a: 1).where(b: 2)
# SELECT things.* FROM things WHERE things.a = ? AND things.b = ?
```

You can also use `.merge` to merge scopes:

```
Thing.where(a: 1).merge(Thing.where(b: 2))
```

Use a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) create a BETWEEN query:

```
Thing.where(foo: (1..10))
# SELECT things.* FROM things WHERE foo BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

This also works for dates and times.

Another thing to bear in mind in that `scope` is just syntactic sugar for class methods. So if your method does not fit in a one-liner you should use the the "classical" method definition:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search_query(query)
    scope = self.all

    terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)
    terms = terms.map { |e|
      (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
    }

    self.all.tap do |scope|
      terms.each do |term|
        scope.merge(
          self.where("(LOWER(students.first_name) LIKE :t OR LOWER(students.last_name) LIKE :t)", t: term)
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```